How do I use positional argument to initialize Pose from geometry_msgs of ROS?
In the documentation, it says that I can initialize with "complete set of field values, in .msg order".
What does this mean? And how do I implement it in Python and C++?

This simply means you can pass __init__ arguments in the order they appear in the .msg file. You would find the exact definition in the geometry_msgs Pose docs here. This is more typically seen as a python paradigm, and uses the * unpacking operator. Such as the following example:
def unpacking_func(*args):
    print(f'I was passed {len(args)} items, they are: ')
    for item in args:
        print(item)
unpacking_func('first', 'second', 'third')

A specific example for the Pose you linked would look like this:
# NOTE: These are just empty values
position = geometry_msgs.Point()
quaternion = geometry_msgs.Quaternion()
pose = geometry_msgs.Pose(position, quaternion)

As a final point I'd note that you linked Diamondback docs, which has been EOL for a long time. This should all hold true for newer distros, but obviously there's no guarantee.

Thank you! But where can I find the new documentation? I searched on Google but could only find this documentation.

@Ben you should go to docs.ros.org. For a more manual search, you can replace the distro name in the URL. For example docs.ros.org/en/noetic will give an index of noetic pages.

The deepest site I can get is here: https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/ It seems like there's no corresponding page for the new docs?

@Ben that page likes to the ros wiki, which also has links to the ros index. What distro are you using and what information are you looking for?

I am looking for the Code API, which indicate what the constructor or other function. https://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/geometry_msgs/html/classgeometry__msgs_1_1msg_1_1__Pose_1_1Pose.html
It seems like there is no such docs for the constructor of geometry_msgs::msg::_Pose::Pose

@Ben if you're just looking for docs on the message types, you should consult the api docs. e.g. this one for Pose. For non-advanced usage you'll be creating messages the same way: by creating an object an assigning the attrs, or simply passing the values in at args.

I see! Thank you!
